# vim: start line number for each section of a file

Tags: vim, line-numbers

I am working on a file which divided into several sections. I knew in vim there are set nu and set rnu for setting line numbering or relative line numbering on all lines. I wonder vim can setup line numbering so that each section has its own line number, such as

```
1 Section A
2 jhkj
3 gfsg
...
1 Section B
2 gfsdg
3 gsdfg
4 gsf
....
1 Section C
2 gs
3 kjgk
...
```

I online searched and can't find help.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that vim gives you that much control over line numbering.  You could open a new, narrow window, paste in the correct line numbers, and use `'scrollbind'`.  This should work fine if you are just navigating, but it will not update automatically.  If you start on Line 1, then this works pretty well:

```
let ln = 0
let lines = []
g/^/let ln = getline('.') =~ '^Section ' ? 1 : ln + 1 | call add(lines, ln)
5vnew
call append(0, lines)
windo setl scb
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot influence the built-in `:set nu` line numbering.

To get something like this, you could use the *signs* feature (its column is right next to the number column), but updating all the signs would be a hassle, especially during line insertion / deletion.

I would suggest looking into the [NrrwRgn - A Narrow Region Plugin similar to Emacs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) plugin. With this, you can split each section into a separate buffer (and `:set nu` there), and any edits there will be automatically synced back to the original by the plugin.